# Limit of a continuous function is a function of a limit?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, continuity, proof-writing

I often heard such a statement "limit of a continuous function is a function of a limit". Is this statement true ? The statement is "$\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = f(\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x))$ if $f(x)$ is continuous and if $g(x)$ has limit at a". I thought about the following proof.
1) Suppose $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x) = b$
2) Now we will do a substitution u=g(x). So as $x$ approaches $a$, $u$ approaches $b$ (from the (1)). Then $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = \lim\limits_{u\to b} f(u)= f(b)$ (we can write last equality because $f(x)$ is continuous).
3) $f(\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x))=f(b)$
4) $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = f(b)= f(\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x))$
Q.E.D

Is my proof valid ? If not, what will be the proof if this statement is true ?  The only thing I don't like in my proof is substitution in (2), is it valid, and if so, is there some formal basis for it ?

Comment: I will edit it soon because looks ugly.

Comment: Your statement is not much clear, are you referring to the definition of continuity?

Comment: @gimusi No. I'm asking "Do continuous functions have such property ?"

Comment: You seem to be having an issue with MathJaX, for instance to get a proper limit use \lim_{x \to a} for $\lim_{x \to a}$

Comment: @gimusi I edited the post, maybe now it is clearer

Comment: Your proof is valid but lacks the proof of "substitution in limits". Also note that you have proved the following: if $f$ is continuous at $b$ and $g(x) \to b$ as $x\to a$ then $f(g(x)) \to f(b) $ as $x\to a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $\lim_{g(x)\to b}$ is not defined.

The easiest way to do this is to use the sequential characterization of limits and continuity.

Let $L = \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ and let $x_n \to a$. By sequential characterization of limits, $g(x_n) \to L$. Then by sequential continuity, $$f(g(x_n)) \to f(L)$$.

Since this holds for any sequence, we have by the sequential characterization of limits that

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(L) = f(\lim_{x \to a}g(x))$$

EDIT-

In response to your comment, what is really being said in #2 is that

$$\lim_{x \to a}(f \circ g)(x) = \lim_{g(x) \to b}(f \circ g)(x)$$ which notationally makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by the statement is not defined ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош see edit

Comment: I read it, I will edit my post, so it will be clearer what I really meant.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Intuitively what you are saying is correct. In terms of rigor, your first equality in #2 needs to be on firmer ground.

Comment: Yeah, I should find some more rigorous way.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош If you google "sequential characterization of limits", the way I posted is an easy way to go about it. This is actually the way it was proved in my real analysis text. There is an equivalence between limits of functions and limits of sequences that allows you to switch back and forth between the two. It is frequently used and worth knowing.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. I will search.

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch2.pdf

Theorem 2.4 here gives a statement and proof of it.