# Interchanging the limit sign of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> If $f(x)$ is continuous and $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} g(x)$ exists, then
> $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(g(x)) = f(\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0}g(x))$$.

my proof:

suppose $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0}g(x) = t$, then according to Heine theorem, we have
$$
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0}g(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} g(a_n) = t
$$
in where $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n = x_0$. And $f(x)$ is continuous, then
$$
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow t} f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(g(a_n)) = f(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}g(a_n)) = f(\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0}g(x)).
$$
so i proved $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(g(a_n)) = f(\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0}g(x))$, but how to prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(g(a_n)) =  \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(g(x))$?
i wonder if the existence of $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(g(x))$ hold the equation ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661886/limit-of-a-continuous-function-is-a-function-of-a-limit

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = L$$ is equivalent to the statement $$(a_n) \to x_0, a_n \neq x_0 \forall n \implies f(a_n) \to L.$$ So your proof is enough.

Comment: It is *enough*, but IMO you can be more clear in stating that in the above, $a_n$ is an arbitrary sequence